# CouchDB: Write and update documents, not read

Tags: database, database-design, permissions, couchdb, pouchdb

Quick question: Is there a way to let a user write (/create) documents and let him update and read his own documents, but not read documents of other users in a shared database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, fine grained security is done as design documents for updates and not for reading. You can:

- use database-per-user and replicate them to the shared database.
- have the user only add to their own _users document as _users implements this special case.